# Application of Bayes' Theorem to dormitory life

Tags: probability

According to the record of the registrar's office at a state university, 35% of the students are freshman, 25% are sophomore, 16% are junior and the rest are senior. Among the freshmen, sophomores, juniors and seniors, the portion of students who live in the dormitory are, respectively, 80%, 60%, 30% and 20%. If a randomly chosen student does not live in the Dormitory, what is the probability that he is a sophmore ?

Comment: And your question about the problem is..?

Comment: what is the answer?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960

Comment: thank you for making fun of my name.

Comment: One little thing: do you really think it's a "real life situation" ?

Comment: This is a question about [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: To give you an idea of how to proceed, sometimes it's useful to start out with some concrete numbers.  Suppose there are $10000$ students at the university (a not unreasonable number).  Then $3500$ are first-years, $2500$ are second years, and so on.  Then of those $3500$ first-years, $80$ percent, or $2800$, live in the dorm, while the remaining $700$ don't.  And so on for the other years.  Add up all those who don't live in the dorms.  What percentage is represented by second-year non-dorm-livers?

Answer (score 1):

An outline leading to the solution:

According to the **definition of conditional probability**,
$P(So|D^c) = P(So \cap D^c)/P(D^c).$

For the numerator: $P(So \cap D^c) = P(So)P(D^c|So) = .25(1-.6) = 0.1.$

For the denominator: 
$$P(D^c) = P(F \cap D^c)+P(So \cap D^c)+P(J \cap D^c)+P(Sr \cap D^c).$$ This is an example of **the Law of Total Probability.**

We have already found one of these four probabilities. Find the other three in a similar way,
and add.

Then do the division for the final answer.

This is an example of **Bayes' Theorem.** (Hence my edit to the title of your question.)

Comment: Still there? Can you find $P(F \cap D^c)?$ Back in a few hours.